# tresos79001 error on vector configurator validation

Tags: vector, configuration, autosar

I got an error after validation check on vector configurator.

I started with a project that has no problem on validation and generation.

But after I added a mcal module 'mem(internal flash)', validation check showed an error.

The error is "Tresos79001 tresos_cmd.bat has returned the ExitCode 1 during Validation"

So I checked below 2 points.

1. validation check of the project's mcal parts on EB Tresos directly. I loaded the arxml of the project on EB Tresos, and added a mcal module 'mem(internal flash)', and executed validation check. and the result showed no error.
2. check the log file of 'tresos_cmd.bat'. I modified 'tresos_cmd.bat' to make log. And I executed validation check on vector configurator, and checked the log file. and it shows 3 errors and details. one of them is as below.

The Xpath-expression "ecu:get('Mem.Infls.WriteSize" caused an error: (35010) The requested ECU resource property "Mem.InFls.WriteSize" does not exist

But I cannot find any 'WriteSize' parameters on vector configurator.

Bnd I cannot find any related parameters with other 2 errors neither.

It seems like the result of validation check on vector configuration and EB Tresos doesn't match.

This is my issue and situations.
I want to know the cause of this problem. Any help will be very helpful to me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, the root cause is that the return code of %CMD% is 1. To solve this, `EXIT /B 0` is appended at end of file.

> "By default, in a batch file, when the execution of commands is completed, the exit code of the batch file will be the return code of the last executed command. If the last command is executed successfully, its return code is typically 0, indicating success or no error. If the last command fails, its return code is usually a non-zero value, indicating an error or an exceptional condition."